# Postgres trigger to update Java cache

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, curl, triggers

I have a Java web app (WAR deployed to Tomcat) that keeps a cache (`Map<Long,Widget>`) in memory. I have a Postgres database that contains a `widgets` table:

```
widget_id | widget_name | widget_value
(INT)       (VARCHAR 50)  (INT)
```

To O/R map between `Widget` POJOs and `widgets` table records, I am using MyBatis. I would like to implement a solution whereby the Java cache (the Map) is updated in real-time whenever a value in the `widgets` table changes. I *could* have a polling component that checks the table every, say, 30 seconds, but polling just doesn't feel like the right solution here. So here's what I'm proposing:

1. Write a Postgres trigger that calls a stored procedure (`run_cache_updater()`)
2. The procedure in turns runs a shell script (`run_cache_updater.sh`)
3. The script base-64 encodes the changed `widgets` record and then cURLs the encoded record to an HTTP URL
4. The Java WAR has a servlet listening on the cURLed URL and handles any `HttpServletRequests` sent to it. It base-64 decodes the record and somehow transforms it into a `Widget` POJO.
5. The cache (`Map<Long,Widget>`) is updated with the correct key/value.

This solution *feels* awkward, and so I am first wondering how any Java/Postgres gurus out there would handle such a situation. Is polling the better/simpler choice here (am I just being stubborn?) Is there another/better/more standard solution I am overlooking?

If not, and this solution is the standard way of pushing changed records from Postgres to the application layer, then I'm choking on how to write the trigger, stored procedure, and shell script so that the entire `widgets` record gets passed into the cURL statement. Thanks in advance for any help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak to MyBatis, but I can tell you that PostgreSQL has a publish/subscribe system baked in, which would let you do this with much less hackery.

First, set up a trigger on `widgets` that runs on every insert, update, and delete operation. Have it extract the primary key and [`NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html)`widgets_changed, id`. (Well, from PL/pgSQL, you'd probably want `PERFORM pg_notify(...)`.) PostgreSQL will broadcast your notification if and when that transaction commits, making both the notification and the corresponding data changes visible to other connections.

In the client, you'd want to run a thread dedicated to keeping this map up-to-date. It would connect to PostgreSQL, [`LISTEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html)`widgets_changed` to start queueing notifications, `SELECT * FROM widgets` to populate the map, and wait for notifications to arrive. (Checking for notifications apparently [involves polling the JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/listennotify.html), which sucks, but not as bad as you might think. See [PgNotificationPoller](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgNotificationPoller) for a concrete implementation.) Once you see a notification, look up the indicated record and update your map. Note that it's important to `LISTEN` before the initial `SELECT *`, since records could be changed between `SELECT *` and `LISTEN`.

This approach doesn't require PostgreSQL to know anything about your application. All it has to do is send notifications; your application does the rest. There's no shell scripts, no HTTP, and no callbacks, letting you reconfigure/redeploy your application without also having to reconfigure the database. It's just a database, and it can be backed up, restored, replicated, etc. with no extra complications. Similarly, your application has no extra complexities: all it needs is a connection to PostgreSQL, which you already have.

Comment: Wow - awesome answer @willglynn (+1) - just curious: I assume I can run a `LISTEN` via JDBC? Also is `PgNotificationPoller` just what Postgres is running under the hood, or is this something I would need to add to my project to make this NOTIFY/LISTEN model work? Thanks again!

Comment: `LISTEN` is a command that causes PostgreSQL to asynchronously push notifications to your connection, delivered in special `NOTIFY`-related messages alongside regular protocol operations. However, there are idiosyncrasies with the way the JDBC driver handles these notifications (due to SSL limitations), so [apparently you need to issue a garbage query](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/-td2172662.html) (`""`) to make the driver see that notifications are available. This is worse than `libpq`, which [needs no round-trips](http://bit.ly/Yt8txO), but still beats polling the table.

Comment: To more directly answer your question, `PgNotificationPoller` and its friend [`PgNotificationHelper`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgNotificationHelper) are two things I found that demonstrate the JDBC `getNotifications()` functionality. You can use these or do it yourself as outlined in [the driver documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/listennotify.html).